# I am trying to display a winning message when score reach 45 on text view

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to display a winning message after the score reach 45 point.
I have used `OnClickListener` to increase point and when the score reach 45 on text view i want to show a toast/pop up message.

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        TextView txtView1, txtView2, txt_point1, txt_point2;
        Button PointBtn, PointBtn2;
    
        int count1 = 0;
    
    
        public void scoreCount() {
            count1 = count1++ + 15;
    
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
    
    
            txt_point1 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.pointView1);
            txt_point2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pointView2);
            txtView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView1);
            txtView1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("player 1"));
    
            txtView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView2);
            txtView2.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("player 2"));
    
            PointBtn = findViewById(R.id.BtnPlus1);
            PointBtn2 = findViewById(R.id.btnPlus2);
    
  
    
            PointBtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    scoreCount();
                    txt_point2.setText( count1+ "love");
    
                    if (count1==45){
                        Toast.makeText(Activity2.this,
                                "Player " +getIntent().getStringExtra("player 1" + " has won"),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else  {
    
                        Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, "You lose", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use next code for Score

```
public void scoreCount()
{
   count1 += 15;
}
```

and after it you can use Dialog window instead of Toast.makeText

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Title")
            .setMessage("Player1 win")
            .setPositiveButton("ОК", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // Close Dialog
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. so where I have to put this method? could you plz tell me about it?

Comment: if you ask about scoreCount() that where you want, if you ask about Dialog in your If(scoreCount == 45)
I see that in your code after click Button you calling scoreCount() after that check scoreCount == 45 or not. But you can use Dialog in method scoreCount too.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong operators in the `scoreCount()` method. Don't use increment operator `++`, it increments `count1` by one and adds 15. Use just `+=` operator:

```
public void scoreCount() {
    count1 += 15;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually by

```
public void scoreCount() {
    count1 = count1++ + 15;
}
```

you are incrementing the variable by 16 and not 15. So remove `count1++ + 15` and make it `count1 + 15`. You may also use shorthand operator `+=`.

```
public void scoreCount() {
    count1 = count1 + 15;
}
```

OR

```
public void scoreCount() {
    count1 += 15;
}
```